# Set active menu to current page by clicking any links outside nav menu

Tags: jquery

The function of the following codes is to add class to clicked link on current page and both of them are working.

```
$("li a").filter(function(){ return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, ""); }).parents('nav ul li').addClass("selected");
```

and

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$("a").each(function() {
  if(this.href == loc) {
     $(this).parents('nav ul li').addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

But my problem is you can only add class to links inside nav. Clicking any links outside the div wont add any class. Please take a look on this url and [click link outside nav1 or 2.](http://funr.net/play/)

1. Which one do you recommend me to use?
2. How to set a default class to the first li(videos) using jquery when I click any links outside nav area?

My goal is to add class to parent li and it's child li selected.

Please help me on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt add a class because you're trying to match the nav item href against the a url which it doesnt match.

You could always add a second part to make sure something is selected

```
var loc = window.location.href;
$("nav a").each(function() {
  if(this.href == loc) {
   $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
  }
});

$("nav").each( function(){
    var $nav = $(this); 
    if ($nav.find('li.selected').length == 0 ){
         $nav.first('.li').addClass('selected');
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply :) This one looks promising but I can make it work. Pls check my updated link http://funr.net/play/outsidelink.php

Comment: It only adds class to nav tag.
    <nav class="selected">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./">Videos</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="videos.php?view=featured">Featured</a></li>  instead of
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="./">Videos</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="videos.php?view=featured">Featured</a></li>